# how to configure ckeditor in Blog component in AEM

Tags: ckeditor, aem

i need to have all ckeditor plugins in RTE of Blog component in AEM,

like http://ckeditor.com/

but the current Blog component in AEM have limited plugins. please check below link. am using AEM 6.2 version
http://localhost:4502/content/community-components/en/journal.html

is this possible ? if yes can some one guide how to do this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You need to overlay /libs/social/commons/components/richTextEditor component. Depending on the libraries you are using (jQuery, etc.) you will need to modify the `document.ready` to load the plugin using the following JS

```
CKEDITOR.plugins.addExternal( [plugin-name], '/etc/clientlibs/path-to-plugin', 'plugin.js' );
```

The plugin can then be registered with CKEDITOR as follows:

```
    var ckEditor = CKEDITOR.replace( [editor-placeholder-element], {
                 toolbar: [{ name: '[toolbar-name]', items: [  '[plugin-name]' ] }],
                 extraPlugins: '[plugin-name]');
```

- The [plugin-name] is the plugin identifier for your plugin based on
  the library.
- The library for plugin is normally stored under
  /etc/clientlibs or your component.
- You can chose an existing toolbar your plugin interface icon or you can create a new one.

  - The plugin and all it's dependencies must be initialised before the CKEDITOR is instantiated or alternatively your plugin must be able to work out its dependencies at runtime.

Hope this helps.

Comment: hi, Thanks for Answer, FYI, am using AEM 6.2 and i referred below link https://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/aem/6-0/author/social-communities/using-rte.html , in Theory "The Communities RichTextEditor component is deprecated in AEM 6.0.  It remains only for form-based social communities JSP-based features"  and we don't have /libs/social/commons/components/richTextEditor  in AEM 6.2 , did you checked in AEM 6.x versions ?